# Which method called when UITableView scroll down and bounce?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i parse some data from XML. I want my table to show first 10 rows, then when user scroll to bottom and table bounce, then it update (load new data from xml) and then show new rows. For example firstly user get 10 rows, then other 10, then rest 10.

I want to know which method is called when tableview bounce to bottom, and some advice how to implement it, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, and `UITableViewDelegate` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. So the delegate you attach to the table view will get events such as `scrollViewDidScroll:`, and you can call methods such as `contentOffset` on the table view to find the scroll position.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;
    // NSLog(@"offset: %f", offset.y);   
    // NSLog(@"content.height: %f", size.height);   
    // NSLog(@"bounds.height: %f", bounds.size.height);   
    // NSLog(@"inset.top: %f", inset.top);   
    // NSLog(@"inset.bottom: %f", inset.bottom);   
    // NSLog(@"pos: %f of %f", y, h);

    float reload_distance = 10;
    if(y > h + reload_distance) {
        NSLog(@"load more rows");
    }
}
```

by neoneye

Comment: This work perfect, thanks! Now i wonder how to change number of rows dynamically, should i user numberOfRows in section method?

Comment: You'll have to update data for your dataSource and update `numberOfRows`, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [this simple control](https://github.com/sishen/LoadMoreTableFooterView). Implement just one `loadMoreTableFooterDidTriggerRefresh:` method, load more rows there, then just call `loadMoreScrollViewDataSourceDidFinishedLoading:`. Quite simple
Some people in answers below gave more exact answers, "which method is called", BUT - this is like inventing reinventing a bicycle, my opinion is that using separate control is just right thing to do.

Comment: Thank you Petro i will download sample project.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` instead of `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView`. It prevents multiple calls to the new rows loading module. In addition, I've made a change in the If line, so it is able to work with scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:

> if(y >= h) {