# Refresh tableView inside UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Objective-C beginner here.
My app structure is as follows:
TabBarController -> NavigationController -> UIViewController -> Table View.
In the table view you can find post objects which I would like to refresh and load more.

If user scrolls from top to bottom I want to delete all posts and then load 5 newest posts.
If user reaches the end of the list I want to load 5 older post.

I tried some suggestions from here and other sites but nothing seems to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451287/which-method-called-when-uitableview-scroll-down-and-bounce This looks like what you want have you had a look at this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment. That helped and no I did not found that post. What I have right now is:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;
    float reload_distance = -100;

    if(offset.y  (h + reload_distance)) {
        NSLog(@"load more rows");
    }
}
```

The code block deletes a if statement before the one that you can see. How is that possible?